# undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA@4' error in C with gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc

My code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
int main ()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("my.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

I have linked winmm.dll in the build options thing on CodeBlocks but I'm getting an error

```
||=== Build: Debug in sound test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||Warning: resolving _SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4 by linking to _SetUnhandledExceptionFilter|
||Warning: resolving _ExitProcess@4 by linking to _ExitProcess|
||Warning: resolving _GetModuleHandleA@4 by linking to _GetModuleHandleA|
||Warning: resolving _GetProcAddress@8 by linking to _GetProcAddress|
||Warning: resolving _FreeLibrary@4 by linking to _FreeLibrary|
||Warning: resolving _PlaySoundA@12 by linking to _PlaySoundA|
||Warning: resolving _GetCommandLineA@0 by linking to _GetCommandLineA|
||Warning: resolving _EnterCriticalSection@4 by linking to _EnterCriticalSection|
||Warning: resolving _TlsGetValue@4 by linking to _TlsGetValue|
||Warning: resolving _GetLastError@0 by linking to _GetLastError|
||Warning: resolving _LeaveCriticalSection@4 by linking to _LeaveCriticalSection|
||Warning: resolving _DeleteCriticalSection@4 by linking to _DeleteCriticalSection|
||Warning: resolving _InitializeCriticalSection@4 by linking to _InitializeCriticalSection|
||Warning: resolving _VirtualQuery@12 by linking to _VirtualQuery|
||Warning: resolving _VirtualProtect@16 by linking to _VirtualProtect|
||Warning: resolving _FindFirstFileA@8 by linking to _FindFirstFileA|
||Warning: resolving _FindNextFileA@8 by linking to _FindNextFileA|
||Warning: resolving _FindClose@4 by linking to _FindClose|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c|| undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA@4'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 18 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: That seems like you're missing to link with the actual libraries (the `.lib` or `.a` files).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thanks for the reply. I have linked libwinmm.a from the path "C:\MinGW\lib" but I'm still getting the error.